# Is it possible to access another jsx components api data from a different jsx file?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, product

I built a product page using useEffect to get information from an API, and then mapping

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api/artProducts.json")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setArt(data));
  }, []); 

          <div id="allList" className={`artList${category.category_id}`}>
            {category.art.map((art) => (
              <div key={art.art_id}>
                <div>
                  <h3>{art.name}</h3>
                  <img
                    src={art.image}
                    alt=""
                    onClick={() => getImg(art.image)}
                  />
                  <NavLink to={`/art-details/${art.art_id}`}>
                    <button type="button">order now!</button>
                  </NavLink>
                </div>
                <p>
                  price{" "}
                  <span>{String(art.price).replace(".", ",")}€</span>
                </p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
```

but I want to create a product details page with more information and I'm stuck on how to connect the two.

I have researched a lot of solutions, this is what I tried to do but all I get is a blank page.

```
export default function ProductPage(props) {
  const [artDetails, setArtDetails] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getResponse();
  }, []);

  const getResponse = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`/api/galeria.json/${props.art.art_id}`).then(
      (res) => res.json()
    );

    setArtDetails(await res);
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <div>
        <h2>{artDetails.art.name}</h2>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: Possible, you need to use (a) State Lifting or (b) React Context API (which is also a state lifting). Basically you need some "parent" entity, like component or context that will execute API call and store this data inside of it in a `state`, and then to pass this data as a `props` or as a `context` to the children consumers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first page, you're fetching `/api/artProducts.json` which seems to be an actual JSON file the server is returning. Unless they literally named the route `/api/artProducts.json` which I doubt.

So then it seems very likely *you're formatting your request to the backend server wrong*. This is not a standard way of formatting an API route request:

`/api/galeria.json/${props.art.art_id}`

You need to create some sort of **API route** that simply handles taking the `art_id` as a parameter, then perform some backend logic to return only the results from `galeria.json` that are related to your `art_id`.

An example express route:

`app.post('/api/galeria/:art_id', (req, res) => { ... });`

Then within the Express handler you access `art_id` using `req.params.art_id`.

Or if you simply want to return all the results from `/api/galeria.json`, you can `filter` the results on the frontend using the art_id. Something along the lines of:

```
const galeriaJSON = [
  { art_id: 1, text: 'hello darkness my old friend' },
  { art_id: 2, text: 'hello world' }
];

const filteredResults = galeriaJSON.filter((row) => {
  return row.art_id === props.art.art_id;
});
```